# Django runserver is working but website isn't loading on other port than 8080: CPANEL

Tags: python, django, port, cpanel

I have two projects of Django, I am using the Cpanel terminal to host this at 8080(WORKING),8083(NOT WORKING)

I am using the Cpanel terminal to host the Django website at port 8083

Now I tried this

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8083
```

[image]

It is working and the server started at 0.0.0.0:8083

Now this should be visible to us in the browser using our `websiteIP:8083`

But this isn't working.

The port 8083 website isn't loading but port 8080

I have checked `ALLOWED HOST =["my.IP.241.0","my_website_url.com"]` in `settings.py`

[image]

It seems to be Firewall issue but don't know how to resolve it..

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. But that's just an educated guess.

Comment: Anything on port 8080 works smoothly but not on other port

Comment: yes it seems to be a firewall issue but confused how to resolve it

Comment: Firewall issues are not on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this article to install csf and disable default firewall of cpanel

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
```

Now install csf and start and enable this

edit csf.conf(Add ports at end you want)

```
TCP_IN="20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,2096,26,8080,8000,8081,8082,8083,8880"
    
TCP_OUT="20,21,22,25,37,43,53,80,110,143,443,587,2086,2087,2083,2082,8080,8000,8081,8082,8083,8880"
```

now run on our python server on our listed ports works

```
screen -d -m  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8880
```

as  this port is supported by cloudflare

I followed this.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-and-configure-config-server-firewall-csf-on-centos